# Calling Action with ajax doesnt show page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I want to call a controller method with an Ajax call. If this is called, another view should be returned. 
When I debug the code, I also reach my controller method. However, the new view is not displayed.
What am I doing wrong?

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult RequestDetails(string requestId, string requestState)
    {
        // ToDo handle parameter

        return View();
    }
```

JS:

```
ShowDetails = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            'requestId': dataItem.RequestId,
            'requestState': dataItem.RequestState
        },
        url: "/Controller/RequestDetails",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

best regards

Comment: An ajax call can't change the current view untill and unless you manually write a code to change the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't show unless you direct it about what to do with the result that is returned from the ajax  call.

You would need to create a container html element on the main View which is currently being displayed on the page firstly:

```
<div id="RequestDetailsContainer">

</div>
```

and then in the `success` callback you will need to put the html returned by controller action to be displayed in that div :

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            'requestId': dataItem.RequestId,
            'requestState': dataItem.RequestState
        },
        url: "/Controller/RequestDetails",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function(response) { // note this function
                    $("#RequestDetailsContainer").html(response);
                 }
    });
```

A side note about the `url` property that, you should be using  `Url.Action` for generating the urls instead of using string  literals like:

```
url: "@Url.Action("RequestDetails","Controller")"
```

Hope it helps.